# Open a modal and link it to a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive defined as follows:

```
app.directive('newTask', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            parentCase: "=",
            options: "="
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/views/task/newTask.html',
        controller: 'newTaskController'
    };
});
```

This works great when I'm using it in the HTML on a page where I want to show it by default using:

```
<new-task parent-case="case" options="options" />
```

However, I'm working on having a modal pop-up and display the page similar to how the other page does it.

To do so, inside of the button click, I have

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/views/task/newTask.html',
            backdrop: 'static',
            controller: 'newTaskController',
            resolve: {
                parentCase: function () {
                    return {};
                },
                options: function () {
                    return { InitialTask: true };
                }
            }
        })
```

This isn't passing 'parentCase' and 'options' through over $scope.  It looks like instead it wants me add parameters to the newTaskController to allow these to come through.  Is there a way to get these to resolve through the new $scope on newTaskController similar to how I do it through the HTML?

Do I need to have a separate "newTaskModal.html" that gets opened instead and just have

```
<new-task parent-case="case" options="options" />
```

on it in order to get the functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: I think you can pass a scope parameter to your $model.open function. Try adding scope: $scope to your obejct.

Comment: Interesting.  If I can do that what's the point of ever using resolve?

It worked by the way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I think you can pass a scope parameter to your $model.open function. Try adding scope: $scope to your object" -- [Komo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3997842/komo)